# How to show previous image in react in image slider?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-redux

I am trying to make image slider in react .I am able to make slider .If you click on `next` button it show the next image .But  I have one issue on `previous` button click, when I clicked
on previous button it is not showing previous image. 
here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/PNzqkxgPl

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./listing.css";
const pics = [
  "http://mumbaimirror.indiatimes.com/thumb/msid-59722654,width-320,height-385,resizemode-4.cms",
  "http://mumbaimirror.indiatimes.com/thumb/msid-59719574,width-320,height-385,resizemode-4.cms",
  "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/07/14/17/44/frog-2504507__480.jpg",
  "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/09/04/13/08/bread-1643951__480.jpg"
];
class Hello extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const idxStart = 0;
    this.state = {
      index: idxStart,
      next: this.getNextIndex(idxStart),
      move: false
    };
    this.next = this.next.bind(this);
    this.pre = this.pre.bind(this);
  }

  getNextIndex(idx) {
    if (idx >= pics.length - 1) {
      return 0;
    }
    return idx + 1;
  }

   getPreviousIndex(idx) {
    if (idx >= 0) {
      return pics.length - 1;
    }
    return idx - 1;
  }
  next() {
    this.setState({
      move: true
    });
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        move: false
      });
      this.setIndexes(this.getNextIndex(this.state.index));
    }, 500);
  }
  pre() {
    this.setState({
      move: true
    });
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        move: false
      });
      this.setIndexes(this.getPreviousIndex(this.state.index));
    }, 500);
  }
  setIndexes(idx) {
    this.setState({
      index: idx,
      next: this.getNextIndex(idx)
    });
  }

  render() {
    const move = this.state.move ? "move" : "";

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="mask">
          <div className="pic-wrapper">
            <div className={`current pic ${move}`}>
              {this.state.index}
              <img src={pics[this.state.index]} alt="" />
            </div>
            <div className={`next pic ${move}`}>
              {this.state.next}
              <img src={pics[this.state.next]} alt="" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button onClick={this.next}>Next</button>
        <button onClick={this.pre}>pre</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Hello;
```

I used the below concept .

- I take two image always .One is `current` and second is `next` .If I
  click on `next` button I  move the `current` image `left` to `0px`
  and next image left to `100`.
  any update

Answer (score 0):

```
  getPreviousIndex(idx) {
    if (idx >= 0) { // this should be if (idx === 0)
      return pics.length - 1;
    }
    return idx - 1;
  }
```

You'll also need a slide left animation :)

HTH.